# Scraping data excluding html tags

Tags: regex, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am working on a project which includes scraping data from websites like uspto.gov using screen-scraper. Now I tried to scrape the website and to some extent, I got success too.

I want to scrape the following line:

Assignee:**Lextine Software, LLC** (Los Altos, CA)

I want "Lextine Software, LLC (Los Altos, CA)" to scrape under "Assignee" so I need to get rid of  which is in-between "Lextine Software, LLC" and "(Los Altos, CA)".

So I need a Regular expression for the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at html parser like Python BeautifulSoup or Java Jsoup..etc. You will never even think about regex after you spend 10 minutes learning those tools.

Answer (score 1):

The basic regex to scrape the substring you are after is:

```
/Assignee:(.*)/
=> "Lextine Software, LLC (Los Altos, CA)"

/Assignee:(.*)\(/
=> "Lextine Software, LLC"
```

Make sure to use the first match!